# Can I vectorise a list comprehension using np.vectorize()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I am fairly new to Python, started with `NumPy`.
I tried to do the following:

```
a = np.arange(1, 20)  
f = np.vectorize([x/(x+1) for x in a])  
f(a)  
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable <-- got this error
```

So I was wondering is it possible to vectorise a list comprehension
Also what does 'object is not callable' mean? for future reference
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: What do you expect when you do `f(a)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't waste time trying to use `np.vectorize`, especially when you can do **real** numpy vectorization.  Don't be fooled by the name.  It isn't a short cut to fast numeric calculations.

```
In [442]: a = np.arange(1,5)
```

your list comprehension:

```
In [443]: [x/(x+1) for x in a]
Out[443]: [0.5, 0.6666666666666666, 0.75, 0.8]
```

can be done with a simple numpy array operation:

```
In [444]: a/(a+1)
Out[444]: array([0.5, 0.66666667, 0.75, 0.8])
```

But let's pretend we have s function that only works with scalar inputs:

```
In [445]: f = np.vectorize(lambda x: x/(x+1), otypes=[float])
In [446]: f(a)
Out[446]: array([0.5, 0.66666667, 0.75 , 0.8])
```

It works, but it's much slower than [444], and not any faster than [443].

Answer (score 2):

> So I was wondering is it possible to vectorise a list comprehension.

`np.vectorize` will transform a function into a function that accepts arrays as inputs. You can then use it instead of list comprehension.

But it does not "vectorize" the operation from a performance perspective. In fact, it is often slower and used for testing or for syntax adjustments.

> Also what does 'object is not callable' mean?

In Python, a "callable" is an object that can be used "as a function". Of course, functions are callables. You can add a `__call__` method to other objects.

Below, an example of a class that has a `__call__` method.

```
In [33]: class myclass():
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         pass
    ...:     def __call__(self, x):
    ...:         return x**2
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [34]: A = myclass()

In [35]: A(10)
Out[35]: 100
```

`[x/(x+1) for x in a]` is an expression, it returns a value, and cannot be called. The argument to `np.vectorize` must be a callable.

Others here suggest to use `np.vectorize(lambda x: x/(1+x))` or

```
def f(x):
    return x/(1+x)

f_vec = np.vectorize(f)
```

The first is a "lambda function", the second a regular functions. Both are callable.

For the case that you show, you can indeed do

```
y = x/(1+x)
```

and that will use NumPy operations. As x is an array, this is considered a form of vectorization (the computation will happen in optimized and vectorized C++ code).

For more complex calculations, look up Cython, numexpr, or Numba.

Comment: Thanks! your callable explanation really cleared it out , I can deal with such error much better now

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be a bit confused as to what list comprehension and what np.vectorize does.
np.vectorize changes a function in a manner such that it can be applied to a list as a whole. What you should be using is -

```
def foo(x):
    return(x/(x+1))

f = np.vectorize(foo)
a = np.arange(1, 20) 

f(a)
```

Using `[x/(x+1) for x in a]` will get you the same result as f(a) just the execution times will be different.

The reason you're getting the "list not callable" error is because f is a list not a function and you're trying to pass an argument (a) to a list.